# Creating columns from rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, pivot

I have this table

```
ID      colname     F1        F2    F3       F4      
1       P1          1         2     3        4
1       P2          5         6     7        8
1       P3          9         10    11       12
1       P4          13        14    15       16
2       P1          17        18    19       20
2       P2          21        22    23       24
2       P3          25        26    27       28
2       P4          29        30    31       32
```

I am trying to produce this result Pn value corresponds to Fn

```
 ID     P1        P2     P3       P4 
 1       1        6      11       16
 2       17       22     27       32
```

can you please give me some hints and keywords on how it could be done with in SQL Server?

i've been playing with Pivot but is it the way to go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you can do something like this:

```
select
     id,
     max(case when colname = 'P1' then F1 end) as P1,
     max(case when colname = 'P2' then F2 end) as P2,
     max(case when colname = 'P3' then F3 end) as P3,
     max(case when colname = 'P4' then F4 end) as P4
from Table1
group by id
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1124f/1)</kbd>**

Comment: thank you nice and simple,max is just to avoid the Group by clause right?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a solution that uses `PIVOT`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT ID,colname,value
  FROM MyTable
  UNPIVOT (value FOR col in ([F1],[F2],[F3],[F4])) a
  WHERE REPLACE(col,'F','P') = colname
) b
PIVOT (MAX(value) FOR colname in ([P1],[P2],[P3],[P4])) c
```

The `UNPIVOT` followed `PIVOT` method is extremely versatile for transforms, but it's usually easier and more readable to do it manually as in Roman's example.